# Twilio WhatsApp Business API

Tags: facebook, twilio, twilio-api, whatsapi

If anyone has worked with Twilio's WhatsApp Business API you may be able to help.

Can you please confirm this: we purchased a UK number from Twilio but we are based and operate in Kuwait. So we will be using the UK number to send WhatsApp messages to users' in Kuwait. Is that fine? Additionally, as we were waiting for Twilio to approve our number we received the attached image and not sure what it means.

We've contacted Twilio support but they're taking a while to respond. Image:

[image: 1]

- Note: we've been approved and Twilio is linked to our Facebook manager. So on the FB side we're good to go, but just waiting for Twilio to approve our sender number so we can use the WhatsApp API.

Answer (score 0):

> So we will be using the UK number to send WhatsApp messages to users' in Kuwait. Is that fine?

Yes! WhatsApp uses phone numbers as identifiers, but the origin country of that phone number doesn't matter, at least technically.

> Additionally, as we were waiting for Twilio to approve our number we received the attached image and not sure what it means.

It appears that perhaps you still have a trial account and someone sent an SMS message to your number. While on trial, you can only send messages to [numbers that you have verified](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio).